# Crawler adds parameter from url to links

Tags: php, http, parameters, apache2, web-crawler

I tried two different web crawler (Sistrix and http://ssitemap.com). Both crawlers report errors about duplicated content for URLs like `/` and `/?katID=12`.

It turns out that if the crawler calls the url `/projekte/index.php?katID=12` it finds `<a href="/">Home</a>` and adds it as link to `/?katID=12`. Looks like the parameter from the url `?katID=12` is added to every link on the page that does not have a parameter.

If I use a browser or wget I see my simple html link to `/` as wanted.

Did I do something wrong? Server config?

Is this a bug or a feature in the crawler?

Comment: Did you try to contact the support of those crawlers? Is this also happening with `wget --recursive` ?

Comment: And did you verify that the `?katID=12` is really added to each link without params? For example by adding links to `/foo` and `/bar` and so on?

Comment: `wget --recursive` works correctly. Yes, I did verify by the link list the crawler returns.

Comment: Then the Sistrix support is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `<link rel="canonical" href="...">` to every page to help crawlers identify equal pages.

See also http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394